# Selenium - Using Portable Firefox 48 with Marionette Driver

Tags: selenium, firefox, firefox-marionette

how is it possible to use marionetteDriver with a FF 48 portable?
I know how it works with installed Firefox 48:

```
String marionetteDriverLocation = getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("[PATH_TO_GECKODRIVER]/wires.exe").getPath();
System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", marionetteDriverLocation);
WebDriver driver = new MarionetteDriver(createDefaultCapabilitiesFirefox());
```

and firefox portable up to 46:

```
FirefoxBinary binary = new FirefoxBinary(new File(firefoxPortablePath));
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(binary, createFirefoxProfile(),createDefaultCapabilitiesFirefox());
```

But what do I have to do when i'd like to use a portable Firefox 48?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try same as you are using for 46. Only changes is just use `setCapability("marionette", true);` into `DesiredCapabilities` as below :-

```
String marionetteDriverLocation = getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("[PATH_TO_GECKODRIVER]/wires.exe").getPath();
System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", marionetteDriverLocation);

DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.firefox();
capabilities.setCapability("marionette", true);

FirefoxBinary binary = new FirefoxBinary(new File(firefoxPortablePath));

WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(binary, createFirefoxProfile(), capabilities);
```

Comment: Its the same result as without marionette=true. The browser starts but displays a white window.

Is it possible, that geckodriver for FF48 only works with Selenium3? I use gecko0.9.0 because the newer one needs WebDriver3/Java8

Comment: What is your current selenium version??

Comment: Selenium 2.53.1  
geckodriver-v0.9.0-win64
Firefox 48.0

Btw. When i use MarionetteDriver with FF portable 44 it works with or without desired cap marionette=true

Comment: Once try with downgraded version of geckodriver to 0.8.0 and let me know..

Comment: Or upgrade your selenium 2.53.1  to 3 with geckodriver 0.10.0 and use same provided code and let me know..

Answer (score 2):

Finally works. gecko 0.8.0 or 0.9.0 makes no difference. Thank you very much @Saurabh Gaur
You made my day!

working code:

```
String marionetteDriverLocation = getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("[PATH_TO_GECKODRIVER]//wires.exe").getPath();
System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver",marionetteDriverLocation);
DesiredCapabilities capabilities = createDefaultCapabilitiesFirefox();
capabilities.setCapability("marionette", true);
WebDriver driver = new MarionetteDriver(capabilities);
```